# How to automatically deallocate memory by a pointer stored in a struct?

Tags: rust

This is the code:

```
use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};
use std::mem::align_of;

struct Foo {
    a: *mut u8
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn make(x : usize) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::from_size_align(x, align_of::<u8>()).unwrap();
            let ptr = alloc(layout);
            Self { a: ptr }
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let foo = Foo::make(100);
    println!("ptr: {:p}", foo.a);
}
```

I'm trying to understand what will happen with the memory when `foo` goes out of scope? Will it remain allocated? Who and how can automatically deallocate it? I know how it works in C++ (manual explicit deallocation) and in Java (garbage collection). What is the canonical approach in Rust?

Comment: Nothing will happen. The `Drop` trait defines what happens when a type goes out of scope. Raw pointers are not given any special consideration so you would need to implement `Drop` for `Foo` yourself to make sure you do not create a memory leak.

Comment: The canonical approach in Rust is not to use pointers at all unless you need them for FFI.

Comment: @Jmb how does `Vec` allocate memory without pointers?

Comment: The standard library uses raw pointers under the hood, regular users usually don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer your question in two parts.

1. How to achieve what you are asking for.
2. Why you probably don't actually want that and what you should do instead.

---

### 1. How to automatically deallocate the memory a pointer points to

By using raw pointers, you opt out of Rusts memory guarantees. You probably realized that yourself already as Rust forced you to use `unsafe` in order to accept your existing code.

One of the consequences is that you are now fully responsible for memory management yourself. Every raw object you allocate via `alloc` requires a deallocation somewhere.

So how do you check whether you have done it correctly? In the same way you need to do it in C/C++: by using [sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_sanitizer).

My personal favourite here is Rusts unstable LLVM-based [`AddressSanitizer`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/compiler-flags/sanitizer.html#addresssanitizer). Note that at the time of writing this, it does not support Windows based platforms yet. So you need to use it in Linux, or if you do use Windows, inside of the WSL.

If I run the very code you show here with the `AddressSanitizer` enabled, I get:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS=-Zsanitizer=address cargo +nightly test
   Compiling rust-tmp v0.1.0 (/home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.47s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/rust_tmp-306d35cce4eb6667)

running 1 test
test test ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s


=================================================================
==18153==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 100 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x55cd3ea24d7e in malloc /rustc/llvm/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69:3
    #1 0x55cd3ea4c5f2 in alloc::alloc::alloc::h61f39024a831bb92 /rustc/af06dce64bf87ea9206bdf6cff61c144b9ce8458/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:93:14
    #2 0x55cd3ea4ff6b in rust_tmp::Foo::make::h02344bcc17d86b06 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/lib.rs:12:23
    #3 0x55cd3ea500cb in rust_tmp::test::h57a614b75a68c4f4 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/lib.rs:20:15
    #4 0x55cd3ea51066 in rust_tmp::test::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hf961bddaf91d900d /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/lib.rs:19:11
    #5 0x55cd3ea8a37e in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h80df756875f70f17 /rustc/af06dce64bf87ea9206bdf6cff61c144b9ce8458/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
    #6 0x55cd3ea8a37e in test::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h54e9d2e6623bf0cf /rustc/af06dce64bf87ea9206bdf6cff61c144b9ce8458/library/test/src/lib.rs:656:18

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 100 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Note the following line in the error:

```
#2 0x55cd3ea4ff6b in rust_tmp::Foo::make::h02344bcc17d86b06 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/lib.rs:12:23
```

Which is the line where we allocated the memory:

```rust
let ptr = alloc(layout);
```

Now that we know that dropping a raw pointer does indeed simply leak memory, how do we fix that?

The proper solution here would be to deallocate the memory whenever `Foo` drops. There is no automated way to do this, raw pointers always have to be deallocated by hand. That said, to make sure it really does always happen when we drop `Foo`, we can add it into its `Drop` implementation.

We hit the next problem, however: [`dealloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.dealloc.html) requires the memory layout as a parameter! Rust by default doesn't know how big the memory is a pointer is pointing to, so it requires the user to provide that knowledge for proper deallocation.

That means we need to store the layout in our struct as well, next to the pointer.

All of this will require `unsafe{ }` again, so be aware that Rust now requires the user to make sure by himself that the code inside of the `unsafe` block is [sound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

All that said, here is the modified code:

```rust
use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};
use std::mem::align_of;
use std::ptr::null_mut;

struct Foo {
    a: *mut u8,
    layout: Layout,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn make(x: usize) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::from_size_align(x, align_of::<u8>()).unwrap();
            let ptr = alloc(layout);
            Self { a: ptr, layout }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            dealloc(self.a, self.layout);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let foo = Foo::make(100);
    println!("ptr: {:p}", foo.a);
}
```

```
$ RUSTFLAGS=-Zsanitizer=address cargo +nightly test
   Compiling rust-tmp v0.1.0 (/home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.96s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/rust_tmp-306d35cce4eb6667)

running 1 test
test test ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests rust-tmp

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

And we don't get any `AddressSanitizer` errors.

---

### 2. Why all of this is a bad idea and what to do instead

Rust raw pointers are not generally meant to be used by the normal user. In general, the entire `unsafe` part of the language is not meant to be used by the normal user. It bypasses one of the main reasons why one would use Rust as a language in the first place: memory safety and safety against undefined behaviour.

The normal, safe, Rust language contains safe mechanisms for almost all normal usecases, and new mechanisms are constantly added to reduce the necessity of `unsafe` as much as possible.

So in your usecase, what would an equivalent `safe` implementation look like?
First, let me try to figure out what your code actually does. From my understanding, you want to allocate a generic byte array of a specific size. The size itself is not a compile time constant, as it is passed in via a variable.

So the memory-managed equivalent of your `*mut u8` would be a `Box<[u8]>`. `Box` is Rust's safe way of making a heap allocation, and `[u8]` is a bunch of bytes. It also has the added advantage that `[u8]` keeps track of its own size, so you don't need to store the size of the allocation anywhere.

`Box<[u8]>` requires on extra step to be created: You need to create `Vec<u8>` (which is the same thing, with the added ability to be resized) and then convert it to a `Box<[u8]>`.

Here is how that could look like:

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: Box<[u8]>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn make(x: usize) -> Self {
        let vector = vec![0; x];
        let boxed_slice = vector.into_boxed_slice();
        Self { a: boxed_slice }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::make(100);
    println!("ptr: {:p}", foo.a.as_ptr());
}
```

(Note I've converted your `test()` to a `main()`, otherwise the `println!()` wouldn't print anything)

```
$ RUSTFLAGS=-Zsanitizer=address cargo +nightly run
   Compiling rust-tmp v0.1.0 (/home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.20s
     Running `target/debug/rust-tmp`
ptr: 0x60b000000040
```

### Further notes

- Probably obvious: no `unsafe{ }` is used. This means the compiler guarantees zero undefined behaviour.
- `vec![0; x]` vs `alloc(layout)` - the `vec` forces an initial value for every element. Reading uninitialized memory is undefined behaviour and forbidden in safe Rust. That would also make your previous code [unsound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html), as `unsafe{ }` code needs to make sure not to leak undefined behaviour into safe Rust. (technically this is incorrect, because you still need `unsafe` to dereference the pointer, so you didn't really leak it into safe Rust yet, but it's a bad idea anyway and very error prone)
- There is no `AddressSanitizer` warning, because no memory gets leaked in the safe example. `Box` (and also all other normal heap allocating structures like `Rc`, `Arc`, `Vec`, etc.) are ownership- and lifetime-managed and get deallocated automatically at the end of their lifetime. Note that this "lifetime" mechanism is (in most cases, except `Rc`/`Arc`) not a runtime thing - it gets figured out at compile time where the object needs to be dropped. So there's no advantage of implementing it manually using `unsafe` over using `Box` - they both perform equally well.
- `dealloc` does not execute any `Drop` implementations, it simply deletes the objects. In the case of `u8` this is not a problem, but for more complex types, be aware that there are better ways than `dealloc` to deallocate raw arrays.

I hope this helped gain a little insight into the philosophy behind Rust, in this particular situation and also in general :)

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: @yegor256 One thing I forgot to mention: I only used `Box<[u8]>` because it is the closest equivalent to your code. In most real-world applications, one would simply use `Vec<u8>` instead.